# Java Annotations Processor: Check if TypeMirror implements specific interface

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, annotation-processing

I'm working with on a Java annotations processor. My annotation, `@foo` is used to mark field variables that can be read to a file or from a file during runtime. However, I would like to check if the variable type implements `Serializable` during compile time, so that if the field is not serializable I can give a warning/error at compile time.

(I don't need to actually check if the object IS serializable, if it implements the `Serializable` interface I'll trust it).

I have figured out how to do the other stuff, but I can't figure out how to check if the element implements `Serializable`. I can use the `TypeElement#getInterfaces` method, but I can't figure out how to check if any of these `TypeMirror`'s returned are the one for `Serializable`.

Also, if anybody happens to know any good `java.lang.model` or Java Annotations tutorials, that would be helpful as well.

Edit: I have tried this...

```
isSerializable = false  
for(TypeMirror tm : processingEnv.getTypeUtils().directSupertypes(em.asType()))  
{  
if(isSerializable = "java.io.Serializable".equals(tm.toString()))  
{  
break;  
}  
}
```

It works alright for String and Character, which directly implement `Serializable`, but for Integer, which inherits Serializable from the Number superclass, it does not work.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Instead of checking the direct supertypes, you should use [`Types.isAssignable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Types.html#isAssignable%28javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror,%20javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror%29) to check if `Serializable` is *one* of the supertypes of the `TypeMirror`:

```
TypeMirror serializable = elementUtil.getTypeElement("java.io.Serializable").asType();
boolean isSerializable = typeUtil.isAssignable(tm, serializable);
```

Comment: Works beautifully! That is faster, cleaner, and now even primitive types like "int" are accepted. =)

Comment: Great! Just what I was looking for

Comment: @kapep I'm sorry I downvoted the answer by mistake, if you can edit the question i will be able to undo the wrong vote.

Comment: @franmontiel No problem, I've made an edit. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing out `Types.isAssignable(…)`—I was looking for such a method! Note that if the type you're comparing is parameterized (e.g. `Collection<String>`), you'll need to use `Types.isAssignable(…)` with a type mirror for `Collection<?>`, which you'll need to construct with an additional step of calling `Types.getDeclaredType(…)`. See my separate [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77212024) to my similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77211537), which is almost a duplicate of this question, but deals with the additional wrinkle of generics parameterization.