# Java Annotation Processor: check if TypeMirror implements specific generic interface

Tags: java, generics, annotations, annotation-processing

I'm writing annotation processor, and I need to check if particular `TypeMirror` implements specific interface.
The question [Java Annotations Processor: Check if TypeMirror implements specific interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358039/java-annotations-processor-check-if-typemirror-implements-specific-interface) provides an answer for non-generic interfaces.
But it doesn't work for generic interfaces, for example `String` is implementing `Comparable<String>` - and the code using isAssignable doesn't work.

This code works as expected:

```
TypeMirror tm = elementUtil.getTypeElement("java.lang.String").asType();
TypeMirror serializable = elementUtil.getTypeElement("java.io.Serializable").asType();
boolean isSerializable = typeUtil.isAssignable(tm, serializable);
//here isSerializable is true
```

But this code doesn't:

```
TypeMirror tm = elementUtil.getTypeElement("java.lang.String").asType();
TypeMirror comparable = elementUtil.getTypeElement("java.lang.Comparable").asType();
boolean isComparable = typeUtil.isAssignable(tm, comparable);
//here isComparable is false
```

I think, that the reason is, that 'comparable' TypeElement is defined with String as generic parameter, but I don't know how to get around it.

Comment: You didn't define `tm`.  Giving full files that can be compiled and run (instead of snippets) will help others to understand your problem and to help you.

Comment: tm is TypeMirror for String, added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Elements.getTypeElement` returns the actual type `Comparable<T>`. `String` is not assigable to `Comparable<T>` but assigable to `Comparable<String>` or `Comparable`. So the most simple way is erasure the generic type by `Types.erasure(TypeMirror)`.

```
TypeMirror tm = elements.getTypeElement("java.lang.String").asType();
TypeMirror comparable = types.erasure(elements.getTypeElement("java.lang.Comparable").asType());
boolean isComparable = types.isAssignable(tm, comparable); // return true
```